# Jenkins - Symfony with environment variables

Tags: symfony, jenkins, continuous-integration, environment-variables

I've been struggling in building automated build using Jenkins with symfony 3.4.

How to properly set environment variables in Jenkins that symfony can find it.

here's my pipeline.

```
node {
def app
stage('composer install') {
    sh 'export $(cat env/env_vars | xargs)'
    sh 'composer install --optimize-autoloader'
}

stage('yarn install') {
    sh 'yarn install'
}

stage ('build assets') {
    sh 'yarn encore production'
}

stage('Clone repository') {
    // clone
}

stage('Build image') {
    // build here
}

stage('Push image') {
  // push here
}
}
```

then after I run my build.

I always got this message

```
....
Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file 
Some parameters are missing. Please provide them.
database_host ('%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'): Script Incenteev\ParameterHandler      
\ScriptHandler::buildParameters handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception


[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
Aborted
....
```

I already used some jenkins plugin like EnvInjector and something similar. But still symfony can't find my environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably solve this like this:

`stage('composer install') {
    sh 'export $(cat env/env_vars | xargs) && composer install --optimize-autoloader'
}`

This will make the environment variables available in the same shell session.